# WCF: KnownTypeAttribute missing in generated proxy

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, proxy

VS2013: WCF service and client.
Service contains class like:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Class2))]
public class BaseClass1 
{
    ...
}
```

When I generate client proxy using Visual studio 2013 'Update Service Reference' then proxy class does not contain KnownTypeAttribute of Class2.
But if I generate it manually using command string:

```
svcutil.exe http://localhost:8082/IService/mex  /noConfig
```

the generated class has this attribute.
Also, VS2010 generates correct  proxy class containing KnownTypeAttribute.

How to solve this problem?